# Getting data from an API in flutter

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

Tring to fetch data using API

My code

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Future<News> news;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    news = fetchNews();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: 
      Container(
        color: Colors.white24,
        child:
        Center(child:
        FutureBuilder<News>(
  future: fetchNews(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {

        /* here if I removed toString() it gives me error
         The argument type 'News' can't be assigned to the parameter type 
         'String'. */ 

       return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("${snapshot.error}");
    }

    // By default, show a loading spinner.
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
           ),
          ),
         )
        );
       }
      }
News newsFromJson(String str) => News.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String newsToJson(News data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class News {
    News({
        this.status,
        this.totalResults,
        this.articles,
    });

    String status;
    int totalResults;
    List<Article> articles;

    factory News.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => News(
        status: json["status"],
        totalResults: json["totalResults"],
        articles: List<Article>.from(json["articles"].map((x) => Article.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "status": status,
        "totalResults": totalResults,
        "articles": List<dynamic>.from(articles.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Article {
    Article({
        this.source,
        this.author,
        this.title,
        this.description,
        this.url,
        this.urlToImage,
        this.publishedAt,
        this.content,
    });

    Source source;
    String author;
    String title;
    String description;
    String url;
    String urlToImage;
    DateTime publishedAt;
    String content;

    factory Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Article(
        source: Source.fromJson(json["source"]),
        author: json["author"] == null ? null : json["author"],
        title: json["title"],
        description: json["description"] == null ? null : json["description"],
        url: json["url"],
        urlToImage: json["urlToImage"] == null ? null : json["urlToImage"],
        publishedAt: DateTime.parse(json["publishedAt"]),
        content: json["content"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "source": source.toJson(),
        "author": author == null ? null : author,
        "title": title,
        "description": description == null ? null : description,
        "url": url,
        "urlToImage": urlToImage == null ? null : urlToImage,
        "publishedAt": publishedAt.toIso8601String(),
        "content": content,
    };
}

class Source {
    Source({
        this.id,
        this.name,
    });

    dynamic id;
    String name;

    factory Source.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Source(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
    };
}

Future<News> fetchNews() async {
  final response = await http.get('My-Api');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    
    return News.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}
```

when I run this Code the output is :
Instance of 'News'

I searched the internet and found most solutions saying I must add await.

The only problem is **THEY DON'T SAY WHERE SHOULD I PUT IT EXACTLY IN THE CODE**

Your help will be appreciated,

Thank you

Note: I'm still a beginner

Comment: You can't (and shouldn't) deal with futures in the `initState` method. Instead, use a [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add `await`. Your code is working correctly. The only thing I would change is

```
FutureBuilder<News>(
   future: fetchNews(),
```

to

```
FutureBuilder<News>(
   future: news,
```

[Here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data) is a very good explanation for this.

Your output `Instance of 'News'` is correct. It's the `model` you declared for the output of your network call. You now have access to it's properties (`status`, `totalResults` and `articles`).

> /* here if I removed toString() it gives me error
> The argument type 'News' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'String'. */

That's because the `Text` widget expects his input to be of typ `String` and not of type `News`.

Comment: I would leave the `FutureBuilder` as-is and remove any reference to `news` entirely. Unless you need to actually manipulate the future itself, you almost never need to store it separately from where it's being used and unpacked.